# Is $\mathbb{R}$ the only ordered field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

A field, in mathematics, means a set $A$, which is an abelian group under an operation "$\ast$", $(A,\ast)$, which is further a commutative ring  with an additional operation, $+$, defined on it  (A,*,+), which when provides assurance that for every element $x\in A$, there exists an element $y$  such that $x+y= e$, where $e$ is the identity element for the operation $+$. 
 Now I read the definition of an ordered field as follow

A field $F$, is said to be an ordered field if there exists two disjoint subsets $P$ and $-P$ (where $-P= \{-x\mid x\in P\,\,\,\}$ ) such that  the union of $P$, $\{0\}$ and $-P$  is $F$, and an element $b$ of $F$ is said to be greater than element $a$ if $b-a$ belongs to $P$, less than if it $b-a$ belongs to $-P$ and equal if $b-a=0$.

Now given this definition  with mentioning of "0", and "-", operation I am convinced to ask  that "Do ordered fields always contain $\mathbb{R}$ or I can say is $\mathbb{R}$ the only ordered field? It will be better if anyone attaches a reference to his answer.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is an ordered field, and so is every subfield of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$, are an ordered field that does not contain $\mathbb{R}$, and are not equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is an ordered field. So is the function field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ under a variety of different orderings, such as the one where $\mathbb{x}$ is a positive infinite number.

Comment: I see we all wrote comments at the same time.

Comment: Also, I would guess that if $F$ is an ordered field, then $F(X)$ is too defining $P$ to be the set of fractions such that the denominator has leading coefficient $=1$ and the numerator has positive leading coefficient.

Comment: There are ordered fields which extend $\mathbb R$ in the sense of allowing infinitesimals. You can have such field extending $\mathbb Q$ without including $\mathbb R$ as well.

Comment: @Primeczar: Your definition of field is incorrect; the field is not an abelian group under $\ast$ (multiplication), because $0$ has no inverse. If $F$ is a field, it *is* true that $F-\{0\}$ is an abelian group under multiplication, though.

Comment: There are a number of equivalent properties you can add to the condition of being an ordered field to uniquely characterize $\mathbb R$; one of these is the least upper bound property, and another is Archimedean + Cauchy sequences converge.

Answer (score 14):

No, there are many other ordered fields. See [the Wikipedia page on ordered fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Examples_of_ordered_fields); some examples of ordered fields that are not $\mathbb{R}$ are

- The rationals, $\mathbb{Q}$
- The real algebraic numbers, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$
- The rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(x)$
- The rational functions over $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}(x)$

Note that $\mathbb{Q}\not\supseteq\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}(x)\not\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, so ordered fields need not contain, or be contained in, $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, as Hurkyl points out below, $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ *neither contains nor is contained in* $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Zevchonoles- Dear Zev,  Thanks a lot for your effort. But actually I intend to investigate can there be ordered fields (if not then fields) which are sets containing no real numbers. All the examples that you have provided contain real numbers. So could you provide any such example?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that while there are many real fields. Any real closed field (a real field without any nontrivial algebraic real extensions) is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}.$ So if a first order statement in the language of ordered fields is true in any real closed field it is true in the real numbers and vise-versa. So in the case you're working with a real closed field and a statement in first order logic, you may as well assume you are working in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @Primeczar: 
That depends what you mean by "contain real numbers". For example, if I take some set $S$ that is in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$, but such that $S\cap \mathbb{R}=\varnothing$, I can make $S$ into a field that is **isomorphic** to $\mathbb{R}$ by "copying" the field structure of $\mathbb{R}$ and putting it onto $S$, and so $S$ will be an ordered field, but it will not contain any real numbers. On the other hand, any ordered field must be of characteristic $0$, and therefore contain (an isomorphic copy of) the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$, which "are" real numbers.

Comment: @Zev: It might be worth mentioning $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ in your examples too, to provide one that is $\subseteq$-incomparable with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Excellent point, I have edited my answer to include that.

Comment: @Zev: $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}$ as a field: take $x$ to any transcendental number.  So $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ admits Archimedean orderings.  (It also admits non-Archimedean orderings...)

Comment: @Pete: That's true (in fact, shouldn't $\mathbb{R}(x)$ also embed in $\mathbb{R}$ by "shifting all the transcendentals over"?), but my sense was that the OP meant just typical set inclusion; unfortunately we haven't gotten clarification from them yet on the matter.

Comment: @Zev: no, $\mathbb{R}(x)$ does not embed in $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is real-closed, the standard ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique field ordering, and thus under $\iota: \mathbb{R}(x) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the restriction of the ordering to $\iota(\mathbb{R})$ must again be the standard ordering, so we have a homomorphism of Archimedean ordered fields $\iota: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  This is necessarily surjective, so there is nowhere for $t$ to map to.

Comment: C.f. Proposition 136 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf.

Comment: @Pete: Ah, thank you for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 13):

The axioms that you mention that define an ordered field are formulated in first order logic.  Any set of first order axioms that have an infinite model actually has models of any infinite size.  This is the upward version of the Loewenheim-Skolem theorem.  So there are arbitrarily large ordered fields.

The Archimedean axiom cannot be formulated in first order logic.
This axiom keeps the fields small, as mentioned above:  Every Archimedean ordered field is isomorphic to a subfield of the reals.

On the other hand, if you add some completeness axiom (every bounded subset has a least upper bound), the field cannot be too small.  Every complete Archimedean ordered field is isomorphic to the reals.  The completeness axiom also cannot
be formalized in first order logic.

Comment: "Every" is an interesting word, though. If "every subset" means ones that can be defined by the theory -- the "real algebraic subsets", then you can formalize completeness and you get real closed fields. On the other hand if "every subset" means every set-theoretic subset of a model, then you get the real numbers of your set theory as you point out.

Comment: Of course I meant every nonempty subset, but that was clear, I suppose.  And you are right, if every means real algebraic, then the theory even has countable models.

Comment: Just adding that, given the definition of completeness that you gave (Dedekind completeness) there is, up to (unique) isomorphism, only one complete ordered field, namely the field of reals. 

There are however Cauchy-complete ordered fields that are non-archimedean, in particular not isomorphic to the reals, however it is true that every Archimedean Cauchy-complete ordered field is isomorphic to the field of reals.

Answer (score 5):

Any ordered field is characteristic 0 and contains an isomorphic copy of the rational numbers. Any field automorphism fixes this copy of the rationals. As a result, little is lost by saying that any ordered field contains the rational numbers, therefore contains "some" real numbers. So this:

"But actually I intend to investigate can there be ordered fields (if not then fields) which are sets containing no real numbers. All the examples that you have provided contain real numbers. So could you provide any such example?"

is not going to work, they all contain infinitely many "real numbers," although, as noted, perhaps not "all" real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Any *Archimedean* ordered field [is (isomorphic to)](http://planetmath.org/archimedeanorderedfieldsarereal) a subfield of $\mathbb R$, though.